# Submit form and redirect not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**EDIT: I should mention the form submits fine manually but with the javascript nothing seems to happen**

I'm trying to get a form to autosubmit on page load and then redirect the user. Reason for this is this is part of a PHP page and the data needs to go into my database but then also POST the variables to a 3rd party SMS platform then return to the users dashboard.

My form looks like this:

```
<html>
   <form action="https://www.example.com" id="myForm" method ="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="apiKey" value="withheld">
      <input type="hidden" name="message" value="<?php echo $club_name ?> have requested you to play for them this weekend. Please login to your account to see more information and accept.">
       <input type="hidden" name="to" value="<?php echo $to ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="from" value="withheld">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</html>
```

This seems to work fine so I assume the Javascript is incorrect which is:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");
</script>
```

Comment: And where did you put the script? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: What actually doesn't work in your code? I guess the redirect. You're submitting a form, and then getting the server response, which is a kind of a redirection. When any server call is pending, changes to `location` object are blocked by browser.

Comment: Didn't realise that so thank you Teemu - however the form itself won't submit which is frustrating me.

Comment: Then read adeneo's comment, maybe you're trying to refer the form before it exists.

Comment: You need to redirect on the server OR use ajax - I strongly suggest you redirect from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a different name than 
name="submit"
as all name attributes are set as properties on the form,
hence overriding the default "submit" property on the form,
and the default form method "submit()" is gone.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement
"Named inputs are added to their owner form instance as properties, and can overwrite native properties if they share the same name (eg a form with an input named action will have its action property return that input instead of the form's action HTML attribute)."

Comment: Thank you this "sort of" worked, the page now redirects which is perfect, however the form still doesn't submit.

Comment: My guess: For the browser both lines are a web request, and as usual (and normally as expectected,  as e.g. when you click on a a link and only moments later on another link on the same page) the first request is cancelled and only the second one is performed. AFAIK there are 2 choices: 1) the submit target has to do the redirect. 2) do not submit, but post the data via ajax, on ajax return, simply ignore the result and do your redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");` line won't make sense because submit() function will try to submit the form and will change the page and then replace function will prevent submitting the form and will redirect the page. The right way to do this via js can be, submit the form via ajax and in the success callback of Ajax run `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`